# How do I disable the command line history in the dash?

Tags: unity, history

Using Unity, how to clear and disable the RUN (ALT+F2) history?

Not the dash history, not the search history --- the ALT+F2 "run" history.

The Privacy Settings Applet of System Settings doesn't seem to cover this box. I found it in gconf-editor

```
/apps/gnome-settings/gnome-panel/history-gnome-run
```

However it's ridiculous going into the editor to delete it each time. The file is

```
~/.gconf/apps/gnome-settings/gnome-panel/%gconf.xml
```

It's dead now (the file, linked to /dev/null) ... and the stupid history is STILL THERE even after I restart. I give up again ... it must be hiding somewhere else, second copy.

---

```
root@qeynos:~$ find . | xargs grep -s NAT097
Binary file ./.config/dconf/user matches
```

Removed that too, nothing broke (so far). Odd that it's in a binary file. Will update after reboot.

---

OK the system has re-created

```
~/.config/dconf/user
```

on boot up and removed my redirection. I am beginning to think this history isn't easily possible to clear. BTW recreating this file also reset my unity launcher and wallpaper to default state.

Answer (score 5):

If the history file is `~/desktop/unity/runner/history`, you may consider link it to `/dev/null`.

that is, in a terminal

```
$ cd ~
$ rm ~/desktop/unity/runner/history
$ ln -s /dev/null ~/desktop/unity/runner/history
```

then logout and login again.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** The below setting (which I've now realized is for 12.04's new app-menu HUD) made me curious enough that I poked around a little more and I think I've found what might just be paydirt.

Also in dconf-editor, `desktop/unity/runner` has the variable `history` with default value of `[]`, here is the description for this variable:

```
Key for storing the history of the Alt + F2 command.
```

No idea what it means by "*key* for storing", or how you might change this.  But given that nothing else seems to have worked it couldn't hurt to play around with this value a bit.  Hope this helps, good luck!

**Original post:**

I just found this setting while doing something else and remembered seeing your question.

using `dconf-editor`, navigate to `com/cannonical/indicator/appmenu/hud`

You'll notice a boolean setting `store-usage-data` with the following description:

```
When the HUD executes operations it stores the execution in order to
make the future results better. Some users could choose to not want
this data to be stored. If that is the case they should disable this
property.
```

I'm skeptical that this could be what you are looking for as 'indicator/appmenu' would be a strange as heck place to put such a setting.  However, having read that description several times now, I can't figure out what else it could mean by "when the HUD executes operations".

Long shot but figured I'd throw it out there.  Good luck.

Comment: Just realized that the HUD is probably the fancy new 12.04 menu-item-finder-thingy.  Reformatting my answer so the more relevant part is first and the original answer is second.

Comment: The edit is the same information that jokerdino posted in the comment to the original question, therefore I cannot award the points for this. It stops history being saved but does not prevent it being recorded. However, I do thank you for taking the time and effort to provide a response. EDIT: That's wrong, it delete the saved history, but doesn't turn it off.

Comment: oh, you're absolutely right, my mistake! I was so excited when I noticed that setting and remembered your question I completely overlooked checking that link before posting... oops!

Comment: @gecko: I just thought of another idea.  Since it is actually storing the history in the dconf key, why not make that specific key read only and rebuild your `dconf/user` file--using the method they use here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/132175/how-to-store-a-dconf-key-as-read-only